# Check available rooms given parameters are room type,start date, and end date

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table

```
**Rooms** 
idRoom
name

**Room_details**
idRoomDetails
idRoom
idRoomType

**Bookings**
idBooking
idRoomDetails
startDate
endDate
```

**Words that have ***  *** are table names**

The variables that I have are idRoomType , startDate, endDate.

How can I output all the rooms that are available and the given parameters are `room type,` `startDate` and `endDate`?

I honestly do not now how to start that's why I can't show you what I've done so far.

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Learn about SQL [JOINS](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: @ChristopherW I know how Join works and other join stuff, the logic of the query is that part that I don't know how to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date selection is your problem than I can give you some useful insights. You should select all rooms with following conditions in your query structure;

```
Booking.startDate  <= "End date of the availability period you're checking"
Booking.endDate    >= "Start date of the availability period you're checking"
```

To make it more clear, your query could look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Rooms
INNER JOIN Room_details ON Rooms.idRoom = Room_details.idRoom
LEFT JOIN Bookings ON Room_details.idRoomDetails = Bookings.idRoomDetails 
WHERE Bookings.idBooking IS NULL
OR (Bookings.startDate <= 'availabilityEndDate'
AND Bookings.endDate >= 'availabilityStartDate')
```

Where 'availabilityEndDate' and 'availabilityStartDate' need to be replaced by actual dates of course.

Comment: Looks like it is working, I've added bookings.idRoomType and the where clause looks like this now WHERE bookings.idBooking IS NULL
AND room_details.idRoomType = 1
OR (bookings.start_date <= '2013-07-30'
AND bookings.end_date >= '2013-07-29')

Comment: I'm sure this will help getting the rooms that are available for you. We developed this 'pattern' many years ago after breaking our necks over a clients request. After we finally solved it the solution was as simple as you see.

Comment: I tested it with data and it seems that it is showing the rooms that is not available within the range of startDate and endDate. Here is the screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/DcoKPisrMQ

Comment: Fixed it (made a mistake in the conditions). The updated version should return available rooms instead of occupied rooms :)

Comment: Should we wrap the dates with quotes? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: If the field is a mysql date field '2013-12-29' should be right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34388/discussion-between-elson-solano-and-rmk)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this query:

```
select * from Rooms r
inner join Room_details rd on
r.idRoom = rd.idRoom
left join Bookings b on
rd.idRoomDetails  = b.idRoomDetails 
where b.idBooking is null
and b.startDate > CURDATE()
```

and b.startDate > CURDATE() should check only for those rooms that have a booking in the future. You might want to try the query without this line first and see if it works. If it does work then you can always add a date checking part to the query.

Comment: It is partly working but the startDate and endDate is not present in the WHERE clause, I think it needs a little more tweaking. I'll try to see. Thanks by the way! :)

Comment: @ElsonSolano see my example (updated it with a example query using the start/end date as I suggested)